# My laptop is becoming slower every day, can't switch between applications without lag

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I'm on a Compaq machine, Intel Core 2 Duo processor, 2GB RAM, Windows 7, Ubuntu 11.10 installed inside Windows 7. I'm using BitDefender anti virus (free version).

My machine is getting slow very rapidly. I don't know the reason. I didn't install any new software lately. I'm just using the machine for word processing and coding, mainly using Office, Netbeans IDE, and other development software.

Even shutting down is slow. The booting time is higher than usual. When I run three applications simultaneously – say MS Word, Firefox and NetBeans – if I switch to NetBeans from Firefox, I can't do anything for about 45 seconds. This time increases every day.

Comment: Seems like normal beheaviour for Windows... You said you're dual-booting with Ubuntu? Does this problem occur on both of them, or only on Windows? That would help us determinse whether the problem is hardware or software related.

Comment: this is happening both of the operating systems,while in Windows it happens quickly, but in Ubuntu it takes some time, but it happens. in Windows i work a lot with 3 or 4 programs open, while in ubuntu only i'm running Firefox and Netbeans no more than 3 programs are run in a given time in ubuntu.

Comment: `installed inside Windows 7` ... You mean Wubi? Well, no wonder Ubuntu's slow. Could also be a hardware problem though.

Comment: if it is true for Ubuntu, what is happening with Windows7? it is the main OS, if it is becoming slow too?

Comment: Windows has always become slow over time, and it always will. Only it seems to be happening a bit fast in your case. If you run Ubuntu from a live USB (not Cd, too slow), is it slow as well? If not, the problem is probably software related, otherwise it's probably hardware related. How old is your computer? Did you install a new hardware component or driver?

Comment: ubuntu is installed inside Windows7, it becomes slow too. roughly near 1year now.no i didn't replace any thing it is the original machine i have bought, no new hardware, components, or drivers.

Comment: ... Yeah but is Ubuntu slow as well when you boot it from a USB drive? You know, a live session?

Answer (score 2):

- Open Control panel
- Search for "Performance"
- First result: Performance Information and tools
- In the sidebar click "Advanced tools"
- At the bottom of the list click "Generate a system health report"
- The application will collect data for 60 seconds, just keep working and after that it will generate a report. In your case it will probably say "The system is experiencing excessive paging" because you don't have much RAM.

Comment: when i first did this system health reporting inspection the program was stuck for roughly one minute then it started working. it didn't gave the error you have given but this was the indication that was given to memory "Memory Normal 59 % 842 MB Available" i'm running 3 applications now, Google Chrome, MSWord, Net beans IDE.

Comment: Is your laptop now slow too?

Comment: yes it is slow. word takes some time to appear. even more time to give me work on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the CPU, HDD and MB temperature maybe your laptop is slow because of overheating. You can do that with [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).

Comment: yes i have installed this software, it does not indicate about a very high CPU temprature? :( no over heating at all ? :(

Comment: You can try turning off automatic backup and see if there are any changes, but i suggest you do a fresh install of the OS and if after that you have the same experience then you may look for the problem in your hardware.

Comment: i have uninstalled UBUNTU, uninstalled the previous virus guard(BitDefender anti virus (free version)) still problem remains the same?

Comment: Did u do a fresh install of Windows or Linux? Have you formated the main partition? You have to format your main partition (or you can format the entire HDD in case you have no sensitive data) This will also check your HDD for errors or bad sectors. See ["this search"](http://www.google.md/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&source=hp&q=site:lifehacker.com+install+windows+7&pbx=1&oq=site:lifehacker.com+install+windows+7&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=383567l387591l1l388085l17l9l0l0l0l0l712l4937l5-6.2l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=3bb28310f70c5c6b&biw=1024&bih=656) to help you through that procedure.